# what version of program X does not contain bug?

Tags: linux, version

Suppose there's a bug in software (linux stuff) you need to use. You don't know if there are newer/older version of program without this bug. How do you find it out?

This question occurred after the next issue: my program worked for a long time, and I didn't know what code causes it. I used `gprof` to find it out but it shows that most of time took `etext`.

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     98.0  204.58    4.77                 etext [1]
```

There is a [stackoverflow `pprof` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301018/golang-what-is-etext) that looks related and answer is bug in `pprof`. I suppose `gprof` has the same bug and I need to get "right" version of `grof`. How do I do it?

I ask the generic question about getting suitable program version, but your help in solving particular case is also appreciated :)

---

UPD1.
Changelog is good but what to do if it doesn't contain information needed?

```
$ apt-get changelog gprof
E: Unable to locate packa
```

[web page](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/binary/) of changelogs for ubuntu doesn't contain changelogs of `gprof`.

Comment: Machine info: Ubuntu 14.04, x64, GNU gprof (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24, program was written in c99.

Comment: You can check [the changelog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14394/apt-changelog-for-to-be-installed-packages) on the latest version available. That lists all changes (including bugfixes) going back to when the package was first made for the given distro. Otherwise you can check various bugzillas (for the upstream project or the major distros, usually Red Hat or Canonical).

Comment: The usual thing to do is to test the most recent version of the software. Ideally one tries to build the latest commit (tip/head) from the version control repository. If that still has the bug, then you should report it.

Comment: Apparently [Canonical keeps changelogs in a web accessible web site](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs) which might be useful. I couldn't find `gprof`'s changelogs though.

Comment: how do I get if it's the latest program version supported by my OS, if program was provided with OS and package manager knows nothing about it?